# Number of sets for which there exists a unique subset for all number from 1 to n such that sum of elements of subset is equal to the number

Tags: set-theory

Given a number n we have to find number of sets such that each number from 1 to n can be **uniquely** formed by adding some of the elements of that set and sum of numbers of the set must be equal to n. For example if n=5 then {1,1,1,1,1}, {1,2,2}, {1,1,3} are valid and {1,1,1,2} is invalid because 3 = 1 + 1 + 1 and 3 = 1 + 2 i.e. 3 is not uniquely formed.Also {1,2,4} is invalid because even it all the number from 1 to 4 are uniquely formed, its sum of elements is 7 not 5. This is a question form CodeChef[(Money Matters)](http://www.codechef.com/problems/MONEY). I have seen some of the answers but still not been able to solve it. Can somebody provide me with some hints or direction?
Range of n : n<10^9

Answer (score 0):

Think of a N by N matrix where each element counts up to N.  Build this matrix with 2 loops.  Then each row that sums to N is a solution.

When N = 5 build:

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 2
0 0 0 0 3
0 0 0 0 4
0 0 0 0 5 SOLUTION
0 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 1 2
0 0 0 1 3
0 0 0 1 4 SOLUTION 
0 0 1 0 1 
etc.
```

Comment: range of n is too high  for matrix

Comment: The matrix is just a concept.  You by definition must be able to return the set of {1,1,1,1....1,1} for a set with N elements.  So, 2 dimensional array of N X N elements could then be tested to see which rows of the array have a sum of N.

Comment: but still checking that would take n^2 computations which would take quite large amount of time. Also I think you misunderstood the problem not only the sum of elements must be n but the numbers from 1 to n-1 should be formed uniquely using the set

Comment: You can exclude the duplicates while you are checking.  And your original post did not specify that the solution needs to be performant.  There will be a LOT of solutions.  I think you will need to brute force it one way or another.  You asked for hints and direction.  I think I provided both.

Comment: Brute force will take exponential time since total number of possibilities is 2^n then for each case we have to check if it satisfies the given conditions so the total running time for n = 10^9 will be in years.

Answer (score -1):

Some recursion could help:

```
function GetSets(int TotalToHit)
{
   solutions += {TotalToHit};
   for int i = 1; i <= TotalToHit / 2; i ++
   {
     solutions += { i, GetSets(TotalToHit - i) };
   }

   return solutions;
}
```